# ASP.NET CORE and EWS Managed API connection problem

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, exchangewebservices

From our intranet web app (Asp.net core 3) I would like to add the ability for users to send emails. We have an on premises MS Exchange Server 2016 (part of our domain).

Following this example from Microsoft: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/get-started-with-ews-managed-api-client-applications
I have put together the following code to send a test email:

```cs
//exchange
ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2013_SP1);
service.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
service.TraceEnabled = true;
service.TraceFlags = TraceFlags.All;
service.AutodiscoverUrl("name.surname@mydomain.com", RedirectionUrlValidationCallback);
EmailMessage email = new EmailMessage(service);
email.ToRecipients.Add("recepient@mydomain.com");
email.Subject = "HelloWorld";
email.Body = new MessageBody("This is the first email I've sent by using the EWS Managed API");
email.Send();
```

```cs
private static bool RedirectionUrlValidationCallback(string redirectionUrl)
{
    // The default for the validation callback is to reject the URL.
    bool result = false;
    Uri redirectionUri = new Uri(redirectionUrl);
    // Validate the contents of the redirection URL. In this simple validation
    // callback, the redirection URL is considered valid if it is using HTTPS
    // to encrypt the authentication credentials. 
    if (redirectionUri.Scheme == "https")
    {
        result = true;
    }
    return result;
}
```

I get a `System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`
error in line: `service.AutodiscoverUrl("name.surname@mydomain.com", RedirectionUrlValidationCallback);`

What am i missing?

EDIT (stack trace):

```
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Autodiscover.AutodiscoverRequest.GetResponseStream(IEwsHttpWebResponse response)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Autodiscover.AutodiscoverRequest.InternalExecute()
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Autodiscover.GetUserSettingsRequest.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Autodiscover.AutodiscoverService.InternalGetUserSettings(List`1 smtpAddresses, List`1 settings, Nullable`1 requestedVersion, Uri& autodiscoverUrl)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Autodiscover.AutodiscoverService.GetSettings[TGetSettingsResponseCollection,TSettingName](List`1 identities, List`1 settings, Nullable`1 requestedVersion, GetSettingsMethod`2 getSettingsMethod, Func`1 getDomainMethod)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Autodiscover.AutodiscoverService.GetUserSettings(List`1 smtpAddresses, List`1 settings)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Autodiscover.AutodiscoverService.InternalGetSoapUserSettings(String smtpAddress, List`1 requestedSettings)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Autodiscover.AutodiscoverService.GetUserSettings(String userSmtpAddress, UserSettingName[] userSettingNames)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService.GetAutodiscoverUrl(String emailAddress, ExchangeVersion requestedServerVersion, AutodiscoverRedirectionUrlValidationCallback validateRedirectionUrlCallback)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService.AutodiscoverUrl(String emailAddress, AutodiscoverRedirectionUrlValidationCallback validateRedirectionUrlCallback)
   at Backend.Controllers.EposteController.PosljiMailTest() in C:\Users\\Desktop\Repos\\Controllers\EposteController.cs:line 216
```

EDIT 2:
We managed to catch some errors on the Exchange server:

```
1**.***.***.*** GET /autodiscover/autodiscover.xml &CorrelationID=<empty>;&cafeReqId=***; 443 - 192.168.1.* - - 401 0 0 10
1**.***.***.*** POST /autodiscover/autodiscover.svc &CorrelationID=<empty>;&cafeReqId=***; 443 - 192.168.1.* ExchangeServicesClient/15.00.0913.015 - 401 0 0 19
1**.***.***.*** POST /autodiscover/autodiscover.svc &CorrelationID=<empty>;&cafeReqId=***; 443 - 192.168.1.* ExchangeServicesClient/15.00.0913.015 - 401 1 2148074254 12
1**.***.***.*** POST /autodiscover/autodiscover.svc &CorrelationID=<empty>;&cafeReqId=***; 443 domain\username 192.168.1.* ExchangeServicesClient/15.00.0913.015 - 200 0 0 137
```

Comment: You need to post full stack trace of exception

Comment: Since error happens inside third party library - I'd file a bug report, because no library should throw NullReferenceException, so I'd consider this a bug.

Comment: so you think there is a bug in Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices ?

Comment: I consider any NullReferenceException a bug, so yes.

Comment: No offence, but it seems a bit far fetched since I'm testing with the most basic example from the Microsoft's link above…

Comment: My point is - this exception should never be thrown, even if you (as a library user) do something wrong. If you ever see NullReferenceException in third party library code - it's a bug, and should be reported to the authors. Here is bug report on their github which might be related to your case: https://github.com/OfficeDev/ews-managed-api/issues/205

Comment: And another similar one: https://github.com/OfficeDev/ews-managed-api/issues/217

Comment: OK, I posted an issue on Github

Comment: I have seen a similar error, caused by a proxy.  Try adding this

<system.net>
    <defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true" />
  </system.net>

To your app.config / web.config

Comment: @Glen: I do not believe there is such a setting for appsettings.json in asp.net core 3

Comment: Indeed, so as per this page ... https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/29147 try adding HttpClient.DefaultProxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
before your call to AutodiscoverURL

Comment: @Glen: I added `HttpClient.DefaultProxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials; ` right before the `service.AutodiscoverUrl("name.surname@mydomain.com", RedirectionUrlValidationCallback);` line, but the error remains the same

Comment: I added some errors that happen on the Exchange server when trying to autodiscover. Maybe this helps??

Answer (score 2):

maybe I can provide an answer. I have an existing WPF application (.NET Framework 4.8, EntityFramework 6.4.4, Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices 2.2.0 (EWS) and other NuGet packages).

A week ago I started a migration to .NET 5, EntityFrameworkCore 5.0.7 and found that EWS was not .NET 5 compatible. There are NuGet packages under .NET Standard but autodiscover does not work according to the authors who advise to fill in Exchange EndPoints by hand.

I downloaded the source code from https://github.com/OfficeDev/ews-managed-api and made a .NET5 Class Library out of it. It compiles. At runtime, there are exceptions during autodiscover. I noticed that an Exchange response had a null ContentEncoding field while this property was used on the next line causing an Exception. The rest of the response seems to be correct, so I added a line at position 483 of AutoDiscoverRequest.cs as below:

if (contentEncoding == null) return responseStream;

It seems to work including autodiscover but this result is only a few hours old.

Answer (score 0):

Are you missing the redirectionUrl parameter?

```
service.AutodiscoverUrl("name.surname@mydomain.com", (redirectUrl) => { return RedirectionUrlValidationCallback(redirectUrl);});
```

Comment: Could you be more specific? I don't know how to implement your suggestion...

Comment: Can you try replacing your service.AutodiscoverUrl line with the one in my answer; passing the redirectUrl to the callback?

Comment: And what shoud I put in for `(redirectUrl)` ?

Comment: The callback should pass that value for you, so you can use it as is.

Comment: Using it as it is does not compile. There are two errors:
1. Cannot convert lambda expression to intended delegate type because some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible to the delegate return type
2. Cannot convert method group 'RedirectionUrlValidationCallback' to non-delegate type 'bool'. Did you intend to invoke the method?

Comment: My apologies, I had the syntax wrong. The updated answer compiles for me.

Comment: OK, It compiles, but the error remains the same: `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`